# I got Segmentation Fault error when I make cat -b function

Tags: c

I want to make 'cat -b' function.

This result is perfect when meet last step.

I got Segmant Fault error and I don't know how to fix it.

How can I do?

```
FILE *file_name = NULL;
file_name = fopen(av[2], "r");
char temp[1024], *str;
int cnt_file_number = 1;
while(!feof(file_name)){
    printf("%4.d ", cnt_file_number++);
    str = fgets( temp, sizeof(temp), file_name);
    if(strcmp(str, "\0") == 0 ) break;
    printf("%s", str);
}
fclose(file_name);
```

Comment: On what line do y ou get the segfault?

Comment: I got a Core dumped

Comment: `file_name` is not a file name. [`while(!feof(...))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

Comment: @hyumil Use a debugger to find which line that causes the segfault.

Comment: What is `"%4.d"` supposed to do?

Comment: This `strcmp(str, "\0") == 0`  is unnecessary. This `if(str == NULL) { break; }` is better.

Comment: Also you need to check return value of `fopen()` to make sure it was success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fgets returns a null pointer if it encounters an error.
<s>You are using str right away without checking it.</s>
A better way would be something like

```
while(fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), file_name) {
    // your printing code but using temp instead of str
}
```

Since fgets returns either temp or null you don't need that extra str pointer and if it is null due to EOF the loop will terminate properly.

Also, checking feof in your loop condition won't do the job because several characters are read at once and EOF might not be the next char but among the next few chars.

Edit: oh sorry. I misread. You are actually checking if str is empty but as others pointed out in the comments there is a better way to do this. Maybe this even solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your program does not reflect the description of what "cat -b" would do, we do not know what `av[2]` is; so, no telling whether that file exists or is readable. It'd be wise to check `fopen()` to ensure that it opens a valid file. If it is not, then it returns `NULL` and `feof(NULL)` will fail.

Also, if you read past the end of file, `str == NULL` and `strcmp(NULL,...)` will fail.

Comment: av[2] means argv[2] when cat hi.txt, av[2] is hi.txt. so, this means FILE NAME

Comment: Okay. Not knowing whether av[2] is valid, my pt still stands. I added another point of failure in my answer, however.